# How to find with a batch file a substring in string inside a loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

This is the code used by me:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)
echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%
set str1=hello
for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do (
    set "str2=!argVec[%%i]!"
    If NOT "!str1!"=="!str1:!str2!=!" set COND=1
    echo !COND!
)
```

This code counts the parameters passed to the batch file and assign them to environment variables. The environment variable `COND` should be defined with `1` only if a parameter string contains the string `hello`.

The problem is in this line:

```
If NOT "!str1!"=="!str1:!str2!=!" set COND=1
```

Variable `COND` is always defined with `1`.

Any ideas how can I solve it?

PS: `str2` is defined with the current parameter (argument) to check for `hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set argCount=0
set "str1=hello"
SET /a cond=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
 set /A argCount+=1
 set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
 IF NOT "%str1%"=="!str1:%%~x=!" SET /a cond=argcount
 ECHO !cond!
)
echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%
GOTO :EOF
```

would show the argument number in which the substring was found as `cond` and `cond` would be set to the last of these finds or 0 if none was found

Comment: It works for one parametre only, when i pass 3 parameters ex : cc he zz the result : 0 2 2 it should give 0 1 0

Comment: Thanks i made a small edit in the script we need to put argcount inside the loop and it's fixed